# The Factory Pattern Equivalent of the Constructor Pattern

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, constructor, factory-pattern

I am using the constructor pattern for creating my objects like below;

```
// Traditional constructor function
const Car = function( color, speed, oil )
{
    this.color = color;
    this.config = { speed: speed, oil: oil };
    // ...
}

Car.prototype.internal = function()
{
    console.log( "internal" );
    // ...
}

Car.prototype.gas = function()
{
    this.internal();
    console.log( this.color );
    // ...
}

Car.prototype.brake = function()
{
    console.log( this.config );
    // ...
}
```

And I want to change my design to an equivalent of this design but with factory functions. So I wrote the following code;

```
// Factory Design with Delegation
const carProto = ( function()
{
    const carPrototype = {};
    // Private function
    function internal()
    {
        console.log( "internal" );
        // ...
    }

    // Public function
    carPrototype.gas = function()
    {
        internal();
        console.log( this.color );
        // ...
    }

    carPrototype.brake = function()
    {
        console.log( this.config );
        // ...
    }

    return carPrototype;
} )();

function carFactory( color, speed, oil ) 
{
    return Object.assign( Object.create( carProto ), 
    { 
        color: color,
        config: { speed: speed, oil: oil } 
    } );
}
```

Finally, I create my objects as follows;

```
var mazdaF = carFactory( "red", 10, 130 );
var mazdaT = new Car( "yellow", 20, 120 );
```

I want to know whether this is correct or not. If this is not true, can anybody help me with the best way to implement that?

Comment: Sure, just paste the code somewhere and run it, it seems to work, and doesn't have any particular deficiencies.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work well for me. It's different syntax than I would use. A key difference in behavior is that your factory allows me to see the internal scope. I can access color and config with `mazdaF.color` or `mazdaF.config` . If you want it to work that way, that's fine. But if you want internal scope to be private to the object, you would use different syntax.

Here is another way (I am not sure this is universal standard practice, so I hope someone else will chime in...):

```
const carFactory2=(c,s,o)=>{
    const color=c;
    const config={'speed':s, 'oil':o};
    const internal=()=>{
        console.log('internal');
    }
    return{
        gas: ()=>{
            internal();
            return color;
        },
        brake: ()=>{
            internal();
        }
    }
}

var mazdaF = carFactory2( "red", 10, 130 );
```

This way actually makes an object that retains the internal scope of the function. `color`, `config` and `internal()` are not accessible outside of the function, and therefore cannot be changed downstream, unless you add a method for it. Here, `mazdaF.gas()` will return the color and execute the internal method. ...But `config` can't be changed either by calling `mazdaF.brake()` *OR* brute force with `mazdaF.config = ...` .

I hope I'm not causing confusion. Again, I think your choice will depend on how you want the internal scope to be used.